# Why do I have staticy sound?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

In Mount & Blade: Warband, I have staticy sound at every other note it seems. Why is that? I went to the Realtek website and got the latest drivers, but it still happens. Using VLC, the audio files sound perfectly fine.

[The Staticy Audio Glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIkbfoW1UQg)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "static sound". Would you be able to record a little bit of it? Do you have any other programs open while playing M&B:WB? Have you tried verifying your game cache in Steam?

Comment: You can also find your M&B:WB music somewhere in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\MountBlade Warband\music` or whatever your Steam folder is. If you play it outside the game, does the same thing happen?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I verified the integrity of my game cache, I just have Steam, Uplay, Origin, and sometimes Discord opened, and recorded a video of it which I linked. You may have to turn your audio up to hear it, but remember to turn it down so you don't blow your ear drums the next video.

Comment: That sounds like very tiny pauses every few ms, as if something is hogging the cpu and the codec can't quite keep up. I would recommend first to close all programs that are not necessary to run the game. If the problem goes away you just have to find out which of the programs is the culprit. Have you tried playing the music outside the game?

Comment: Maybe related steam support topic: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4911-eicn-7411&l=dutch

Comment: @Sumurai8 My i7-3820 3.60 GHZ 4-core CPU most likely isn't getting hogged from a Mount & Blade: Warband. I can't also find a program that can open .ogg files.

Comment: You could download a codec pack for such formats (e.g. https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). Meanwhile you could try the solutions in the steam support topic, as I believe that is the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow: VLC can open them, as any other media files, without needing codec.

Comment: I was reading somewhere else that the default audio handler for certain file types may be the cause of some of this glitching..  I don't think this applies to games as much as it does websites, but that being said, you could dig into the registry or sound manager and see if there is a program or codec that can be updated and see if it makes a difference to the sound?

Answer (score 3):

***Because you seem to be having a unique experience with this, I think the following things are worth looking at, just as a bit of a check list.***

1. Is anyone else having the same problem?
2. If you use other Headphones/speakers does the problem persist.
3. Does dropping the total volume help?  (In game and in Windows Sound Manager)

The above three will help you identify where in the chain the static is coming from.

**Question 1:**

- Yes? Problem with the game
- No?  Problem with your hardware/software

**Question 2:**

- Yes? Headphones/speakers are damaged.
- No?  not your headphones/speakers.

**Question 3:**

- Yes? The Sound card has a maximum amplitude that it can output, you are surpassing that, and as such your sound card (or other sound output device) is not powerful enough to drive your speakers/headphones at the volume you are trying to achieve.  (Fix and then test Question 2 again, your light headphones, will behave differently from your heavy speakers)
- No?  Something between the software and your hardware is not playing fair.
  If the problem is unique to this game, blame the game!  If it's happening for more that just this game (try running some others at full volume (max it out))  then blame the drivers/hardware

***If you're using a built in sound device  (can still do if you don't mind replacing your existing PCI card):***
Find a local tech person and ask them if they have a spare sound card (These are practically junk PIC cards that most people never need/use so they just pile up.) Give him a $20 and ask him to throw it in your PC.  (PS: Woot upgrade :) )
See if that fixes the issue, if it does, blame the original card for having limited scope, bandwidth, power, or just wearing out.
If this does not fix the issue, (New Hardware, New Drivers, Different Headphones)  Then the only options left are 'Your game' and 'Your Operating System'  If it's windows, blame windows.  Else blame the game.

***Side notes:***
"win+r" -> "dxdiag" has a sound section that can give you some details about your sound device.

Comment: Question 1: I have seen some threads about it from years ago. Question 2: Both my Razer Kraken 7.1 Chromas and Speakers are having this issue. Question 3: I dropped my Volume Mixer from 50 to about 25. Still happens.

Comment: Drop Windows Sound Managers volume as well, And the in game volume.    You want to stay away from the peak output of your software and hardware if you're testing the 'load' on your devices.  What solutions did the threads from Q1 have?

Comment: I just saw "Update Realtek drivers". Pretty much it.

Comment: Ok then go with the assumption that your driver/card is not up to the task, (and since you already said you had updated your drivers)  Try to get your hands on either a USB sound card, or new PCI card to test with.  ( a quick search on Amazon - https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb+sound+card)

Answer (score 0):

My question to you:

Is this custom audio files that you placed in the game folder? And if so, did you have to convert the audio files to .ogg?

If your answer is "yes", then I know a possible solution:

Yesterday, I had been having trouble with audio files in-game (Not Mount and Blade, but the premise is still the same). What had happened is that after audio conversion, and after launching the game, the custom audio files that had been converted to .ogg file format began having a loud staticy sound, so much audio interference that I couldn't make out what audio file was actually playing.

But I later realized that the problem didn't lie in my hardware or drivers, but rather in the conversion process itself. During the final and additional options directly before the conversion process, I had not seen that you had the option to choose the "sound rate" at which the audio files were converted. But I tested this theory, and converted another single audio file, and the sound rate (Hz) that I selected the file to be after conversion was "44100 Hz". Because this is the default audio sound rate for default audio files on the majority of modern PC's and other hardware. I launched my game, and tested the newly converted audio file, and the audio file played perfectly and clearly with 0% static or any other type of interference.

So, in simple terms, the steps to be taken in this situation are as follows:

1. Convert audio file(s).
2. At the last step before the conversion process starts, select the sound rate "44100 Hz" for all audio file(s) that are to be converted.
3. Place audio file(s) in their designated folder, unless you have already chosen the designated folder as the audio file(s) output directory.
4. Launch your game and test the audio file(s), if the audio plays clearly and without interference then you have solved your problem. If not then there is another reason for your audio having static interference, and is more than likely a hardware or driver issue as stated by TolMera above.